# PHP: mail() attaching base64 image comes out as text

Tags: png, base64, php

I have been trying to encode an image as base64 then sent it as an email attachment using php mail(), but all I am getting is the base64 text in my email.  Here is what I am using:

```
$boundary1 = 'bound1';
$boundary2 = 'bound2';
$to = 'test@me.com';  
$subject = 'Test Image attachment'; 
$headers = 'From: "Me" <me@myemail.com>'."\r\n"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary1\""; 
//define the body of the message. 
$message = 'Content-Type: image/png; name="'.$file_name.'"'."\n"; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; 
$message .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$file_name\"\n\n";
$message .= base64_encode_image("signature_files/".$file_name, 'png')."\n";
$message .= "--" . $boundary2 . "\n";
//send the email 
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Function to encode an image
function base64_encode_image($filename=string,$filetype=string) {
    if ($filename) {
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
        return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . chunk_split(base64_encode($imgbinary), 64, "\n");
    }
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this code?  Really not sure why I am just see RAW text when I recieve the email.

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) and save yourself all of this hassles. They both do attachments and inline images with ease,

Comment: @Marc - It is a great idea, but I don't have the luxury on this project.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way for sending HTML email with inline base64 image:

```
<?php
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$header[] = "Content-Type: Multipart/Mixed; Boundary=\"$boundary\"";
$header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
$header[] = "From: John Doe <john.doe@pbx.com>";
$header[] = "Reply-To: John Doe <john.doe@pbx.com>";
$header[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

$msg[] = "";
$msg[] = "--{$boundary}";
$msg[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
$msg[] = "";
$msg[] = "<p>YOUR HTML CONTENT</p> <img src=\"cid:logo\" alt=\"Logo\">";
$msg[] = "";
//HERE YOU MUST ATTACH THE IMAGE
//===============================================
$image = chunk_split(YOUR_IMAGE_ENCODED_IN_BASE64);
$msg[] = "--{$boundary}";
$msg[] = "Content-Type: image/png; name=\"logo.png\"";
$msg[] = "Content-ID: <logo>";
$msg[] = "Content-Description: Attachment";
$msg[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
$msg[] = "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"logo.png\"";
$msg[] = "";
$msg[] = $image;
$msg[] = "";

$msg[] = "--{$boundary}--";
mail($mailto, $subject, implode("\r\n", $msg), implode("\r\n", $header));
```

The important part here is the content id reference, so, first, you must define your image id, in this case, the id is **logo**, so, in the attachment, you must define the content ID header:

```
Content-ID: <logo>
```

Then, in the HTML content, you may call or attach inline this image by the content ID, as shown below:

```
<img src="cid:logo" alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `\r\n` and `\n\n` in your message headers and MIME attachment part headers respectively.  Try changing them all to `\r\n`.

Another possibility - if you are trying to attach the image, rather than display inline, use `Content-disposition: attachment;`

```
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\n\n";
```

Comment: Fixed those things and am still having the issue.

Comment: @Nic Are you certain it's not your `base64_encode_image()` function?  Try using plain `base64_encode()` to return the raw image instead.

Comment: I actually thought it might be that, so I did what you suggested and it still doesn't work.